# Why can I not add to a linked list correctly when using a function?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to a create a linked list. When I add to the list in the same function that I create the object in, it works.

Definitions:

```
typedef struct student {
    int num;
    char* name;
} student;

typedef struct container {
    student* data;
    struct container* next;
} container ;
```

All the objects I use are initialized like this:

```
student stu1;
stu1.num = 6;
stu1.name = "grefagf";

front = createContainer(&stu1);
back = front;

student stu2;
stu2.num = 3;
stu2.name = "dsghjyreawre";

student stu3;
stu3.num = 4;
stu3.name = "dsghhjrant";

student stu4;
stu4.num = 213;
stu4.name = "fdsafgrw";
```

When I add these elements to a list in the main function like this:

```
container* tmp;

tmp = createContainer(&stu2);
back->next = tmp;
back = tmp;

tmp = createContainer(&stu3);
back->next = tmp;
back = tmp;

tmp = createContainer(&stu4);
back->next = tmp;
back = tmp;
```

it works properly, outputting this:

```
1:  6       grefagf
2:  3       dsghjyreawre
3:  4       dsghhjrant
4:  213     fdsafgrw
```

when I print it using another function I made.

But if I create a function called `add()` and pass stu2, stu3..., like so:

```
int add(student to_add) {

    container* tmp;
    tmp = createContainer(&to_add);
    printf("added: (%d, %s)\n", tmp->data->num, tmp->data->name);

    back->next = tmp;
    back = tmp;

    return 1;
}
```

then do this in the main function:

```
add(stu2);
add(stu3);
add(stu4);
```

it outputs this:

```
1:  6       grefagf
2:  41096808        fdsafgrw
3:  41096808        fdsafgrw
4:  41096808        fdsafgrw
```

Heres the source in case you need it:

Non-function example: https://pastebin.com/ZLqTzp4t

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student {
    int num;
    char* name;
} student;

typedef struct container {
    student* data;
    struct container* next;
} container ;

container* back;
container* front;

container* createContainer(student* data) {

    container* tmp = malloc(sizeof(container));

    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    return tmp;
}

void printList(container* front) {

    container* tmp = front;

    int i;
    i=0;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        i++;
        printf("%d:\t%d\t\t%s\n", i, tmp->data->num, tmp->data->name);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}

int main(void) {

    student stu1;
    stu1.num = 6;
    stu1.name = "grefagf";

    front = createContainer(&stu1);
    back = front;

    student stu2;
    stu2.num = 3;
    stu2.name = "dsghjyreawre";

    student stu3;
    stu3.num = 4;
    stu3.name = "dsghhjrant";

    student stu4;
    stu4.num = 213;
    stu4.name = "fdsafgrw";

    container* tmp;

    tmp = createContainer(&stu2);
    back->next = tmp;
    back = tmp;

    tmp = createContainer(&stu3);
    back->next = tmp;
    back = tmp;

    tmp = createContainer(&stu4);
    back->next = tmp;
    back = tmp;

    printf("front\n");
    printList(front);
    printf("\ntop\n");
    printList(back);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Function example: https://pastebin.com/TyQY4j5k

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student {
    int num;
    char* name;
} student;

typedef struct container {
    student* data;
    struct container* next;
} container ;

container* back;
container* front;

container* createContainer(student* data) {

    container* tmp = malloc(sizeof(container));

    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    return tmp;
}

int add(student to_add) {

    container* tmp;
    tmp = createContainer(&to_add);
    printf("added: (%d, %s)\n", tmp->data->num, tmp->data->name);

    back->next = tmp;
    back = tmp;

    return 1;
}

void printList(container* front) {

    container* tmp = front;

    int i;
    i=0;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        i++;
        printf("%d:\t%d\t\t%s\n", i, tmp->data->num, tmp->data->name);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}

int main(void) {

    student stu1;
    stu1.num = 6;
    stu1.name = "grefagf";

    front = createContainer(&stu1);
    back = front;

    student stu2;
    stu2.num = 3;
    stu2.name = "dsghjyreawre";

    student stu3;
    stu3.num = 4;
    stu3.name = "dsghhjrant";

    student stu4;
    stu4.num = 213;
    stu4.name = "fdsafgrw";

    add(stu2);
    add(stu3);
    add(stu4);

    printf("front\n");
    printList(front);
    printf("\ntop\n");
    printList(back);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: [Please don't link to your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), but produce a proper [mcve] in the question itself. It'd seem that you're passing a struct by value to `add()`, but you've not included the definition of `student`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I wanted to include both an example with the function and without and I figured it would be easier to link to pastebin where it's easy to copy/paste than to write it here. And I added the function definitions.

Comment: Please rethink; we shouldn't need to go offsite to see the code you're asking about.  Read up on creating an MCVE ([MCVE]). Minimal is important; so is complete.  Note to that the code `student stu1; stu1.num = 6; stu1.name = "grefagf";` is not an initializer for `stu1`; it assigns values to it.  It would be initialized with `student stu1 = { 6, "grefagf" };` or `student stu1 = { .num = 6, .name = "grefagf" };` — where the second uses designated initializers.  (IOW: "initializer" is a technical term in C and applies to 'assigned when defined'.)

Comment: why do not you give the address of stu2 to add function such as add(&stu2) and revise your functions as  int add(student * to_add)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I could get this to work using simpler objects, but I still can't get it to work like how I have it now, so I can't really strip much more from it to create an MCVE. 

Thanks for the tip on initializers, I'll use that from now on.

Comment: @RedArrow That is what was wrong, thank's a lot! Do you know why that caused the problem?

Comment: it seems about casting because your num variable seem take address values now i will try your code and return to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i tried it is working. Only get by address student structs to your add function 
as below

```
add(&stu2);
add(&stu3);
add(&stu4);
```

and change function of add as below

```
int add(student *to_add) {

    container* tmp;
    tmp = createContainer(to_add);
    printf("added: (%d, %s)\n", tmp->data->num, tmp->data->name);

    back->next = tmp;
    back = tmp;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more or less minimal version of your code with the `add` function.  It runs at 60 lines compared to 83 for your original.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student
{
    int num;
    char *name;
} student;

typedef struct container
{
    student *data;
    struct container *next;
} container;

static container *back;
static container *front;

static container *createContainer(student *data)
{
    container *tmp = malloc(sizeof(container));
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    return tmp;
}

static void add(student to_add)
{
    container *tmp = createContainer(&to_add);
    printf("added: (%d, %s)\n", tmp->data->num, tmp->data->name);
    back->next = tmp;
    back = tmp;
}

static void printList(container *item)
{
    for (int i = 0; item != NULL; item = item->next)
        printf("%d:\t%d\t\t%s\n", ++i, item->data->num, item->data->name);
}

int main(void)
{
    student stu1 = { 6, "grefagf" };
    student stu2 = { 3, "dsghjyreawre" };
    student stu3 = { 4, "dsghhjrant" };
    student stu4 = { 213, "fdsafgrw" };

    front = createContainer(&stu1);
    back = front;
    add(stu2);
    add(stu3);
    add(stu4);

    printf("front\n");
    printList(front);
    printf("\nback\n");
    printList(back);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

On my Mac, it produced:

```
added: (3, dsghjyreawre)
added: (4, dsghhjrant)
added: (213, fdsafgrw)
front
1:  6       grefagf
2:  0       
3:  0       
4:  0       

back
1:  0
```

The problem is that you are passing the address of a local variable to your `createContainer()` function, but that variable goes out of scope so your container is pointing at garbage. Since this is invoking undefined behaviour, the results can be different on your machine, and both will be correct.  A crash is also possible — that's one of the beauties of UB.

You need to revise it in one of two ways.  Either `createContainer()` makes a copy of what it is passed, or you arrange to pass pointers to the variables in `main()` through `add()` to `createContainer()`.  This code does the second — but it is probably not the better solution in the long run.  However, there's (a lot) more memory management to deal with for a general solution copying what's passed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student
{
    int num;
    char *name;
} student;

typedef struct container
{
    student *data;
    struct container *next;
} container;

static container *back;
static container *front;

static container *createContainer(student *data)
{
    container *tmp = malloc(sizeof(container));
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    return tmp;
}

static void add(student *to_add)
{
    container *tmp = createContainer(to_add);
    printf("added: (%d, %s)\n", tmp->data->num, tmp->data->name);
    back->next = tmp;
    back = tmp;
}

static void printList(container *item)
{
    for (int i = 0; item != NULL; item = item->next)
        printf("%d:\t%d\t\t%s\n", ++i, item->data->num, item->data->name);
}

int main(void)
{
    student stu1 = { 6, "grefagf" };
    student stu2 = { 3, "dsghjyreawre" };
    student stu3 = { 4, "dsghhjrant" };
    student stu4 = { 213, "fdsafgrw" };

    front = createContainer(&stu1);
    back = front;
    add(&stu2);
    add(&stu3);
    add(&stu4);

    printf("front\n");
    printList(front);
    printf("\nback\n");
    printList(back);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There are 5 characters different here from the last version.  There's a `*` in the function definition of `add()`; there's no `&` in the call to `createContainer()`; there is an `&` in each of the calls to `add()` in `main()`.  The result is:

```
added: (3, dsghjyreawre)
added: (4, dsghhjrant)
added: (213, fdsafgrw)
front
1:  6       grefagf
2:  3       dsghjyreawre
3:  4       dsghhjrant
4:  213     fdsafgrw

back
1:  213     fdsafgrw
```

This code leaks memory because it doesn't attempt to clean up the list.  That's OK for the time being.  Just be aware that you'll need to clean up eventually.

Comment: How would I 'clean up the list'?

Comment: You'd step through from front to back, freeing the containers, and then set front and back to point to NULL once more. `static void freeList(container *item) { while (item != NULL) { container *next = item->next; free(item); item = next; } front = back = NULL; }`

Comment: Oh, as in like freeing the memory? Do I only need to do that once I'm finished using the list? When would a memory leak occur? (also, what is a memory leak?) Sorry for so many questions.

Comment: Yes, you free the list when you're finished with it.  The memory leak occurs if your code moves on without freeing the now unused list.  In this program where the list is in use until the program exits, it is not critical to free it — that's why it's "OK for the time being".  However, if you're working with functions called from `main()`, the unreleased list becomes leaked memory when you can no longer access it.  Again, with a single list maintained by global variables, it isn't an immediate problem.  If you generalize the code (make it into a subroutine library), it becomes an issue.

Comment: A memory leak occurs when allocated memory can no longer be accessed but has not been freed.  For example, if you have a function that allocates a string, formats some data into that string, prints it to the screen and a log file, and then returns — well, that memory is almost certainly no longer accessible and is leaked.  It will never be used again, but it is still allocated to the program. For long running programs, memory leaks are a problem.  For short running student exercises, they're not a major problem.

Comment: So "leaked memory" just means wasted memory that is being unnecessarily taken up by the program?

Comment: More or less.  You can have wasted memory that isn't technically leaked — but leaked memory is wasted memory.  (Wasted but unleaked memory is still accessible, but is simply not going to be used again.  Leaked memory isn't accessible — and because it isn't accessible, it won't be used again and is very much wasted.)

Comment: Nice answer. Just one thing - reason for making the methods `static` is to have the file level scope of the function?

Comment: @coderredoc: Under the rules and compiler options I use for C, if functions (other than `main()`) are not static, then there must be a header to declare the function, and the only reason for introducing a header is because there are at least two source files using the code.  Similarly with variables, too — if they're not static, there must be a header declaring them and more than one source file using them.  By declaring them static when they're defined and before they're used, I avoid having to put declarations at the top of the file and then repeating the information in the definition. …

Comment: _[…continued…]_ But I use fussier options than most people do.   I start with `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes` and sometimes add some more on top of that.  So, when answering SO questions with code, I just make functions and variables static automatically and usually without comment, though I'm happy to explain if asked.

Comment: I guess it is the `-Wmissing-prototypes` that makes you do that. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

The add function should also consume the linked list (or "container") that it is adding the "student" to.

Thus, you should not be creating a "temp" container in it, but using the passed in container and adding to the back of that passed in container.

EDIT: Just realized your back and front are global. This probably isn't a good idea, because that way you can only have a single linked list for your entire program.

Rereading now...

EDIT 2: Ahh this was a good one. You are passing in student (which makes a copy of the student) and *then* taking its address in the add function, which is an address of a variable on the stack. The stack is popped off so address to variables on the stack don't make sense.  Instead, add should take in a pointer to a student, and you should pass in the address of stu2, stu3, etc.

EDIT 3: Ahh too late :(

Comment: What do you mean by 'consume'? The passed in variable is the object that I want to add, and it creates a container to store it in, then adds that container to the back of the list.

Comment: Sorry, edited. I didn't realize your "front" and "back" pointers were global variables. (unrelated) "consume" is another way of saying a function takes as an "input", i use it to avoid confusion with I/O i.e. inputs from standard input.

Comment: Ah okay. And I did have back and front passed to the function as well (not global) but it wasn't working, so I tried making them global because that's the way my professor always does it. I only need one linked list for this program anyway, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Edited with reply